# Google Authentication in python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, google-authentication, aws-secrets-manager

I am trying to get authentication to use the google translation API. Currently on my local machine I simply do this:

```py
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_to_cred_json_file
translate_client = translate.Client()
```

which works fine. However, I wish to do this on AWS where I have I stored the credential json file in AWS secrets. In the documentation for `translate.Client` I see this:

```py
Init signature:
translate.Client(
    target_language='en',
    credentials=None,
    ...
)
...

:type credentials: :class:`~google.auth.credentials.Credentials`
```

However, if I read in the json file and try to pass it in as the credentials argument it chucks an error.

The only answer I have for now in AWS is to read the secret, write it out as a json file, and then set `os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = path_to_cred_json_file`, which will work, but was told by a data engineer is a security risk.

So the question is how do I get this `google.auth.credentials.Credentials` object without reading a physical file. I have access to the plain text version of the json file in memory (via AWS secrets). I'm really new to AWS in general so go easy on me.

Comment: [`google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info`](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/google.oauth2.service_account.html#google.oauth2.service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @miles-budnek and [this](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/4477#issuecomment-347765112) github comment, found the answer.

Supposing I have the json string as a dictionary called `secret`:

```py
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_info(secret) 
t_client = translate.Client(credentials=credentials)
```